# PYTHON - Dificuldades em arrumar código COH-PIAH

Tags: python

Boa noite, estou fazendo um curso em python e esse é o último exercício do curso, mas eu estou tendo muita dificuldade em corrigi-lo, quando eu envio dá o seguinte erro:

"***** [0.5 pontos]: Testando avaliação dos textos (Textos = ['Navegadores antigos tinham uma frase gloriosa:"Navegar é preciso; viver não é preciso".Quero para mim o espírito [d]esta frase,transformada a forma para a casar como eu sou:Viver não é necessário; o que é necessário é criar.Não conto gozar a minha vida; nem em gozá-la penso.Só quero torná-la grande,ainda que para isso tenha de ser o meu corpo e a (minha alma) a lenha desse fogo.Só quero torná-la de toda a humanidade;ainda que para isso tenha de a perder como minha.Cada vez mais assim penso.Cada vez mais ponho da essência anímica do meu sangueo propósito impessoal de engrandecer a pátria e contribuirpara a evolução da humanidade.É a forma que em mim tomou o misticismo da nossa Raça.', 'Voltei-me para ela; Capitu tinha os olhos no chão. Ergueu-os logo, devagar, e ficamos a olhar um para o outro... Confissão de crianças, tu valias bem duas ou três páginas, mas quero ser poupado. Em verdade, não falamos nada; o muro falou por nós. Não nos movemos, as mãos é que se estenderam pouco a pouco, todas quatro, pegando-se, apertando-se, fundindo-se. Não marquei a hora exata daquele gesto. Devia tê-la marcado; sinto a falta de uma nota escrita naquela mesma noite, e que eu poria aqui com os erros de ortografia que trouxesse, mas não traria nenhum, tal era a diferença entre o estudante e o adolescente. Conhecia as regras do escrever, sem suspeitar as do amar; tinha orgias de latim e era virgem de mulheres.', 'NOSSA alegria diante dum sistema metafisico, nossa satisfação em presença duma construção do pensamento, em que a organização espiritual do mundo se mostra num conjunto lógico, coerente a harmônico, sempre dependem eminentemente da estética; têm a mesma origem que o prazer, que a alta satisfação, sempre serena afinal, que a atividade artística nos proporciona quando cria a ordem e a forma a nos permite abranger com a vista o caos da vida, dando-lhe transparência.'] , Assinatura = [4.79, 0.72, 0.56, 80.5, 2.5, 31.6] ) - Falhou *****
AssertionError: Esperado: 2; recebido: 1"

Esse é o código que usei:

```
import re


def le_assinatura():
    """
    A função lê os valores dos traços linguísticos do modelo e devolve uma
    assinatura a ser comparada com os textos fornecidos.
    """
    print("Bem-vindo ao detector automático de COH-PIAH.")

    tam_m_pal = float(input("Entre o tamanho medio de palavra: "))
    type_token = float(input("Entre a relação Type-Token: "))
    h_lego = float(input("Entre a Razão Hapax Legomana: "))
    tam_m_sent = float(input("Entre o tamanho médio de sentença: "))
    compx_med = float(input("Entre a complexidade média da sentença: "))
    tam_m_frase = float(input("Entre o tamanho medio de frase: "))

    return [tam_m_pal, type_token, h_lego, tam_m_sent, compx_med, tam_m_frase]


def le_textos():
    i = 1
    textos = []
    texto = input("Digite o texto: " + str(i) + "(aperte enter para sair):")
    while texto:
        textos.append(texto)
        i += 1
        texto = input("Digite o texto: " + str(i) + "(aperte enter para sair):")
    return textos


def calcula_assinatura(texto):
    """
    Essa função recebe um texto e deve devolver a assinatura
    do texto.
    """
    if type(texto) != list:
        aux = texto
        texto = []
        texto.append(aux)
    for i in texto:
        sentencas = []
        sentencas = separa_sentencas(str(i))  
        frases = []
        num_tot_sentencas = 0
        soma_cat_sentencas = 0
        for i in range(len(sentencas)):
            frase_i = separa_frases(str(sentencas[i]))
            frases.append(frase_i)  
            num_tot_sentencas += 1
            soma_cat_sentencas = soma_cat_sentencas + len(sentencas[i])
        palavras = []
        num_tot_frases = 0
        soma_cat_frases = 0
        for lin in range(len(frases)):
            for col in range(len(frases[lin])):
                palavra_i = separa_palavras(str(frases[lin][col]))
                palavras.append(palavra_i)  
                num_tot_frases += 1
                soma_cat_frases = soma_cat_frases + len(str(frases[lin][col]))
        mtrx_para_lista = []  
        for lin in range(len(palavras)):
            for col in range(len(palavras[lin])):
                mtrx_para_lista.append(palavras[lin][col])
        palavras = mtrx_para_lista[:]
        soma_comp_palavras = 0
        num_tot_palavras = 0
        for lin in range(len(palavras)):
            for col in range(len(palavras[lin])):
                soma_comp_palavras = soma_comp_palavras + len(str(palavras[lin][col]))
            num_tot_palavras += 1
        matriz_ass_input = []
        matriz_ass_input.append(tam_m_pal(soma_comp_palavras, num_tot_palavras))
        matriz_ass_input.append(type_token(palavras, num_tot_palavras))
        matriz_ass_input.append(h_lego(palavras, num_tot_palavras))
        matriz_ass_input.append(tam_m_sent(soma_cat_sentencas, num_tot_sentencas))
        matriz_ass_input.append(compx_med(num_tot_frases, num_tot_sentencas))
        matriz_ass_input.append(tam_m_frase(soma_cat_frases, num_tot_frases))
    return matriz_ass_input  


def tam_m_pal(soma_comp_palavras, num_tot_palavras):
    if num_tot_palavras != 0:
        tam_m_pal = soma_comp_palavras / num_tot_palavras
    else:
        tam_m_pal = 0
    return tam_m_pal


def type_token(lista_palavras, num_tot_palavras):
    num_pal_dif = n_palavras_diferentes(lista_palavras)
    if num_tot_palavras != 0:
        type_token = num_pal_dif / num_tot_palavras
    else:
        type_token = 0
    return type_token


def h_lego(lista_palavras, num_tot_palavras):
    num_pal_uni = n_palavras_unicas(lista_palavras)
    if num_tot_palavras != 0:
        h_lego = num_pal_uni / num_tot_palavras
    else:
        h_lego = 0
    return h_lego


def tam_m_sent(soma_num_cat, num_sent):
    if num_sent != 0:
        tam_m_sent = soma_num_cat / num_sent
    else:
        tam_m_sent = 0
    return tam_m_sent


def compx_med(num_tot_frases, num_tot_sentencas):
    if num_tot_sentencas != 0:
        compx_med = num_tot_frases / num_tot_sentencas
    else:
        compx_med = 0
    return compx_med


def tam_m_frase(soma_cat_frases, num_tot_frases):
    if num_tot_frases != 0:
        tam_m_frase = soma_cat_frases / num_tot_frases
    else:
        tam_m_frase = 0
    return tam_m_frase


def separa_sentencas(texto):
    """
    A função recebe um texto e devolve uma lista das sentenças dentro
    do texto.
    """
    sentencas = re.split(r'[.!?]+', texto)
    if sentencas[-1] == '':
        del sentencas[-1]
    return sentencas


def separa_frases(sentenca):
    """
    A função recebe uma sentença e devolve uma lista das frases dentro
    da sentença.
    """
    return re.split(r'[,:;]+', sentenca)


def separa_palavras(frase):
    """
    A função recebe uma frase e devolve uma lista das palavras dentro
    da frase.
    """
    return frase.split()


def n_palavras_unicas(lista_palavras):
    """
    Essa função recebe uma lista de palavras e devolve o numero de palavras
    que aparecem uma única vez.
    """
    freq = dict()
    unicas = 0
    for palavra in lista_palavras:
        p = palavra.lower()
        if p in freq:
            if freq[p] == 1:
                unicas -= 1
            freq[p] += 1
        else:
            freq[p] = 1
            unicas += 1

    return unicas


def n_palavras_diferentes(lista_palavras):
    """
    Essa função recebe uma lista de palavras e devolve o numero de palavras
    diferentes utilizadas.
    """
    freq = dict()
    for palavra in lista_palavras:
        p = palavra.lower()
        if p in freq:
            freq[p] += 1
        else:
            freq[p] = 1

    return len(freq)


def compara_assinatura(ass_main, matriz_ass_input):
    """
    Essa função recebe duas assinaturas de texto e deve devolver o grau de
    similaridade nas assinaturas.
    """
    lista_Sab = []
    soma_mod = 0
    if type(matriz_ass_input[0]) is list:
        for lin in range(len(matriz_ass_input)):
            for col in range(len(matriz_ass_input[lin])):
                soma_mod += abs(ass_main[col] - matriz_ass_input[lin][col])
            Sab = soma_mod / 6
            lista_Sab.append(Sab)
        return lista_Sab
    else:
        for i in range(len(matriz_ass_input)):
            soma_mod += abs(ass_main[i] - matriz_ass_input[i])
        Sab = soma_mod / 6
        return Sab


def avalia_textos(textos_main, ass_comparadas):
    """
    Essa função recebe uma lista de textos e deve devolver o numero (0 a n-1)
    do texto com maior probabilidade de ter sido infectado por COH-PIAH.
    """
    aux_ass_com = (ass_comparadas[:])
    aux_ass_com.sort()
    for indice in range(len(ass_comparadas)):
        if aux_ass_com[0] == ass_comparadas[indice]:
            copiah = indice
    return copiah -1
```

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, vou inserir como deve funcionar o programa, pra deixar um pouco mais claro.

"Diversos estudos foram compilados e hoje se conhece precisamente a assinatura de um portador de COH-PIAH. Seu programa deverá receber diversos textos e calcular os valores dos diferentes traços linguísticos da seguinte forma:

Tamanho médio de palavra é a soma dos tamanhos das palavras dividida pelo número total de palavras.
Relação Type-Token é o número de palavras diferentes dividido pelo número total de palavras. Por exemplo, na frase "O gato caçava o rato", temos 5 palavras no total (o, gato, caçava, o, rato) mas somente 4 diferentes (o, gato, caçava, rato). Nessa frase, a relação Type-Token vale 45=0.8
Razão Hapax Legomana é o número de palavras que aparecem uma única vez dividido pelo total de palavras. Por exemplo, na frase "O gato caçava o rato", temos 5 palavras no total (o, gato, caçava, o, rato) mas somente 3 que aparecem só uma vez (gato, caçava, rato). Nessa frase, a relação Hapax Legomana vale 35=0.6
Tamanho médio de sentença é a soma dos números de caracteres em todas as sentenças dividida pelo número de sentenças (os caracteres que separam uma sentença da outra não devem ser contabilizados como parte da sentença).
Complexidade de sentença é o número total de frases divido pelo número de sentenças.
Tamanho médio de frase é a soma do número de caracteres em cada frase dividida pelo número de frases no texto (os caracteres que separam uma frase da outra não devem ser contabilizados como parte da frase).
Após calcular esses valores para cada texto, você deve comparar com a assinatura fornecida para os infectados por COH-PIAH. O grau de similaridade entre dois textos, a e b, é dado pela fórmula:

**Sab=∑6i=1||fi,a−fi,b||6**

Onde:

Sab é o grau de similaridade entre os textos a e b;
fi,a é o valor de cada traço linguístico i no texto a; e
fi,b é o valor de cada traço linguístico i no texto b.
Perceba que quanto mais similares a e b forem, menor Sab será. Para cada texto, você deve calcular o grau de similaridade com a assinatura do portador de COH-PIAH e no final exibir qual o texto que mais provavelmente foi escrito por algum aluno infectado."